# How can I insert data into a sql table with Dapper with nested object

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public ProductType Type { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Vendor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public VendorType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to save Product with Vendor information, but in my task I must use insert with nested object without dapper.contrib. In my table Product I have vendors id information with all vendors in another table.

Without nested I can write this, but as I said: I have a task to write with nested.

```
var request = "insert into Products values (@vendorId, @name,
@price, @description, @category, @type)";

db.Query<Product>(request, new {vendorId = prod.Vendor.Id, 
name = prod.Name, price = prod.Price, description = prod.Description, 
category = prod.Category, type=prod.Type  });
```

Comment: Dapper isn't going to unroll nesting for you. If you want that kind of feature: use an ORM like EF, or figure out what the insert order is yourself: and do that with Dapper